# Expected Value when joint density function is given

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X_i$ denote the percentage of votes cast in a given election that are for candidate $i$, and suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a joint density function
$f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)= 3(x+y)$ if $x\geq0;y\geq0;0\leq x+y \leq1$ else $f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)= 0$.

Find $E[X_i]$ for $i=1,2$?

Is it correct to say $E[X_i] = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} (x+y)f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)$?

Comment: Contrarily to an assertion below, one does not have to compute first the marginal densities, instead one can go directly at the heart of the matter, using $$E(X_1)=\iint xf_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)dxdy$$ and $$E(X_2)=\iint yf_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)dxdy.$$ Finally, note that the integral you suggest is $$\iint (x+y)f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)dxdy=E(X_1+X_2)=E(X_1)+E(X_2).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate $E[X_1]$ and $E[X_2]$ respectively you have calculate first the marginal densitiy functions:

$f_{X_1}(x)=\int_0^{1-x} 3(x+y) \, dy=\frac32(1-x^2)$

$f_{X_2}(y)=\int_0^{1-y} 3(x+y) \, dx=\frac32(1-y^2)$

Then

$E[X_1]=\int_0^1 x\cdot  f_{X_1}(x) \, dx $

$E[X_2]=\int_0^1 y\cdot f_{X_2}(y) \,dy$